# How to map SQL Server `varbinary(max)` field with NHibernate ByCode mapping?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class with a property of type `byte[]` that I would like to map to a `varbinary(max)` field in SQL Server using the new NHibernate ByCode mapping.

So far, using `SchemaAction = SchemaAutoAction.Recreate` in order to have NH create the schema, I've ended up with the following (the class property name is "Data"):

- When mapping is not qualified in any way, I end up with a `varbinary(8000)` field
- When mapping is `map.Property(x => x.Data, m => m.Length(int.MaxValue))`, I end up with an 'image' field (which, according to SQL Server docs, will not be supported in the next release of SQL Server)
- When mapping is `map.Property(x => x.Data, m => m.Type(TypeFactory.GetBinaryType(int.MaxValue))`, I end up with a `varbinary(8000)` field, which just seems wrong

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and this has worked for me.

```
Property(e => e.Data, m => m.Column(cm => cm.SqlType("varbinary(MAX)")));
```